# File Permissions using batch file

Tags: batch-file, icacls

This is my script.

```
@echo off

set USER = %1

if [%1]==[] goto error

icacls \\TESTSERVER\testusers\%user% /grant:r "%USER%":(OI)(CI)F

icacls d:\testusers\%user% /grant:r "%USER%":(OI)(CI)F

@echo Folder Permission set successfully

goto end

:error

 @echo Error 101- Username Parameter invalid-Please provide a valid username as Parameter

:end
```

And this is the output:

```
processed file: \\TESTSERVER\testusers\
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
processed file: d:\testusers\
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
Folder Permission set successfully
```

Instead of applying permissions to folder specified by user, the script is applying permission to parent folder.

also when I see the security tab of testuser folder instead of user name I find some account name S-1-5-21-710178827-4191585984.....

What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a <kbd>space</kbd> in your `set user=` statement. This sets a variable `"User "` not `"USER"`

Spaces are significant on each side of <kbd>=</kbd> in a string `set`.